# How can I select a specific row and column from a DBGrid lazarus?

Tags: pascal, lazarus

I want to save a specific value that is on a specific row and column. How I can do this? I already search, but I didn't find anything

Answer (score 0):

One doesn't save a value from the grid but rather from the underlying dataset. The following is for Delphi, but I understand that Lazarus is near enough the same. Let's say that the grid is displaying data from a query qTest that has fields id, surname, forename, date of birth (DOB). In Delphi, one can automatically have variables created with names qTestID, qTestSurname, etc. Another way of referring to the variables is by use of the 'fieldbyname' syntax - qTest.fieldbyname ('surname').asstring.

Write a dblClick handler for the grid: when one gets to the row that holds the required data, perform a double click. In the handler, the fields of the row will now be available as qTestID.asinteger, qTestSurname.asstring, etc.